# Calculate the Golden Ratio by using Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: swift, sequence, fibonacci

There is a Swift code for a n-th Fibonacci number

```
func fibonacci( n: Int) -> Int {
if n == 0 || n == 1 { return n; }

else { return fibonacci(n: n - 1) + fibonacci(n: n - 2) }
}
print(fibonacci(n: 10))
```

I wan to calculate the Golden Ratio by using Fibonacci numbers

How can I make  a list of  `F(n+1) / F(n)` for n=2 to n=10

I tried something like this :

```
func fibonacci( n: Int) -> Float {
if n == 0 || n == 1 { return n; }

else { return fibonacci(n: n - 1) + fibonacci(n: n - 2) }
}


func phi( k: Int) -> Float {

Phi = fibonacci(n: k)/fibonacci(n: k)
}


print(Phi(n: 10))
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck at? Please add your code to do that task and the error messages you get (or whatever) to the question. We won't write code for you, we only help with specific problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use arrays.

```
func fibonacci(n: Int) -> Float {
if n == 0 || n == 1 
    { return 1.0; }
else { 
       return fibonacci(n: n - 1) + fibonacci(n: n - 2)
   }
}

var goldenRateArr = [Float]()

func phi(k: Int){

goldenRateArr.append( (fibonacci(n: k+1)/fibonacci(n: k)))

if (k > 2)
   { phi(k:k-1) }

}

phi(k:10)
print(goldenRateArr)
```

And your output would be:

```
[1.6179775, 1.61818182, 1.61764705, 1.61904764, 1.61538458, 1.625, 
1.60000002, 1.66666663, 1.5]
```